# Supabase: is it possible to return data from multiple tables? (no reference or foreign key)

Tags: supabase

Let's say I have three tables: `post`, `discussion`, and `article`.

Is it possible to return all content from all 3 tables?

Something like `supabaseClient.from("post", "discussion", "article").select()` ? (this doesn't seem to work).

Basically I need to build an admin page that lists all content, with the ability to search their title and sort them by some column (which they all have in common). So ideally being able to return all of the content with one query would be great.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not. You need to fire three queries.

```js
const {data: posts} = await supabaseClient.from("post").select()
const {data: discussions} = await supabaseClient.from("discussion").select()
const {data: articles} = await supabaseClient.from("article").select()
```

Comment: Ah, that's what I feared. So what would be the strategy if I want to be get the combined first 50 items of these three tables ordered by a common field, and then paginate to the next 50?

Comment: @Hubert You can create a view that combines the three tables, and query it. https://supabase.com/blog/postgresql-views